# How to use OneDrive Business authentication without web control (from console application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, onedrive, office365api

I'm having trouble signing in **OneDrive for Business** API from my console application. I couldn't find any code sample for sign in method, and my attempt to create a call to:

```
GET https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}
&response_type=token&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

But when I take a look at response it's login form. And I don't get it why even for "native" (console application) I have to specify redirect_uri which will be used as callback after authentication.

Is there a way to login automatically without that web control, so basically from my console application?

Comment: It's an [OAuth service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). So you need to pass authentication to it and tell it where to redirect. It's designed for use on the web only. The idea is that the user authenticates on the live web site and you **never see the username or password**. Therefore the users security is withheld by the authenticating party. So you need a web browser to facilitate this.

Comment: So I can't use OneDrive for Business API from my console application in order to upload files automatically?

Comment: Not in the way that you are. Maybe they implement a different API for console apps, I don't know. But you can't use HTTP OAuth the way you are

Comment: Not in the method you are attempting.  Doesn't OneDrive give you an access token (what the oAuth service does) to use so that you can upload files to your own directory?

Comment: You should really read this MSDN section on using OAuth offline - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243649.aspx

Comment: @Tommy that's what I'm trying to get, but in order to get token I need to pass step 1 first. https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm which means that I need user interaction...so that wouldn't be automated process at all!

Comment: So basically in order for someone to fully automate upload he needs to avoid their API because it is useless if you want to implement it in service or something similar... and to use a workaround like Selenium WebDriver or similar...

Comment: It's August 2018 and I don't think Microsoft has provided API auth without browser interaction

Comment: @PrakashPandey it's doable now. I did it recently in the new app, and I was postponing the update for older app which was using `WebBrowser` trick with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize` and JS automation to capture `?code=` after "manual" (automated) login :). It's doable now in more elegant way with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}` (use your tenantID here) and `AuthenticationContext` from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` and you can pass some user credentials to obtain results token like `authContext.AcquireToken(resourceId, clientId, uc);`

Comment: @PrakashPandey ...since the comment was longer continuing here...once you get token you can do anything you like with your graphClient and somethig like: `
            graphClient.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath("path").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(yourStream);`

Comment: @PrakashPandey check this demo gist (din't try it but it should work with maybe some minor tweaks about references): https://gist.github.com/vsavic/5e1b786be3436fbbeb6f030bf00bc630

Comment: Awesome, I will try. If you find some time in future, you can write a nice blog about it

Comment: @ShP The link you shared is in .net, Do you have any equivalent python code?

Comment: @PrakashPandey I have only code for .net. But take a look here, seems like they have demo for python https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app workflow seems pretty much the same.